# How to write golang code in html file (gin gonic framework)

Tags: go, go-gin

Im newbie in golang code as well as in gin gonic. I got a problem while using gin gonic.

In my controller. i get all articles and render to html file by code.

```
c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "articles/list", gin.H{
    "title":    "Articles",
    "articles": articles,
})
```

and articles have field "CreatedOn" type int64 (created date)
So in my view list.html, how i can parse CreateOn type int64 to date format.

```
<div class="list-group">
  {{ range $article := $articles }}
    <a href="/articles/{{ $article.Id }}" class="list-group-item">
      <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{ $article.Title }}</h4>
      <p class="list-group-item-text">{{ $article.Body }}</p>
      <p class="list-group-item-text">{{ $article.CreatedOn  }}</p>
      <p class="list-group-item-text"></p>
    </a>
  {{ end }}
  </div>
```

Thanks all

I had found a way that i write a method FormatDate()

```
func (a *Article) FormatDate(ab int64) string {
    return "test Time"
}
```

in model "Article". then in my view i call

```
  <p class="list-group-item-text">{{ .FormatDate article.CreatedOn  }}</p>
```

Anything else????

Comment: Isn't your `FormatDate()` approach working?

Comment: ofcourse it's worked. it is a method, i want to build a helper function for template but dont know how to declare anf call it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **TL;DR** use SetHTMLTemplate

Looking at the **Gin** [documentation](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin), you can use your own templating engine.

By invoking **r.SetHTMLTemplate(tmpl)**

**Gin** itself is using the golang builtin html/template standard package.

You can use the same engine and add **user defined functions**.

Create the functions, using template.FuncMap:

```
funcMap := template.FuncMap{
    "formatTime": func(raw int64) string {
        t := time.Unix(raw, 0)

        return t.Format("Jan 2 15:04:05 2006")
    },
}
```

Instantiate a template:

```
tmpl := template.Must(template.New("main").Funcs(funcMap).ParseGlob("templates/**/*"))
```

Register the new template:

```
r := gin.Default()
r.SetHTMLTemplate(tmpl)
```

If you use same templates name for different endpoints, specify name:

```
{{ define "articles/list.tmpl"}}

<div class="list-group">
{{ range $article := .articles }}
  <a href="/articles/{{ $article.Id }}" class="list-group-item">
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{ $article.Title }}</h4>
    <p class="list-group-item-text">{{ formatTime $article.CreatedOn }}</p>
    <p class="list-group-item-text"></p>
  </a>
{{ end }}
</div>

{{ end }}
```

> formatTime: Is defined using template.FuncMap

To invoke, use the normal way:

```
c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "articles/list", gin.H{
    "title":    "Articles",
    "articles": articles,
})
```